# Improve SEO for the "funny" site name of SE websites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, seo

I'm sorry for the very cryptic title but I couldn't come up with a better wording.

Many SE websites have two names:

- The first is basically a description of what the website is about, such as **Food and Cooking**.
- The second is a "funny" name: **Seasoned Advice**.

Since the funny name is usually in the header image (such as on [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)) it's likely that most of the visitors will use *Seasoned Advice* to refer to the cooking website.

But there has been zero SEO effort to get the website in google search results for the "funny" name. In fact:

- http://www.seasonedadvice.com permanently redirects and thus won't ever be in google results.
- https://cooking.stackexchange.com/ doesn't contain the words "Seasoned Advice" **anywhere** except in the header image, which google can't crawl.

This leads to extremely poor SEO performance: [see this search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=&q=seasoned%20advice).

I think it should be something very important to get right, because if I tell my friend to go to "seasoned advice" and they can't find it through google then they'll probably give up.

Comment: I'm guessing this is intentional: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

Comment: That is a very long blog post without saying much or actually explaining the reason for the reversal. And there isn't a clear separation between domain name and site name. *"...rolling back ASAP was preferable to letting problems grow exponentially..."*. What problems? 1) SEO problems (e.g., should the (sub)domain name be equal to the site name? Own separate domain vs. under the common .stackexchange.com)? 2) Community discontent with naming choices (domain name? site name? Or both?)? 3) Or something else?